# In Single Top mode it is not loading data into listview Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-relativelayout

In single top mode activity, I am successfully getting data using asynctask but I am unable to load data into ListView. Same code working in onCreateView. I am using Android Search widget.

This is my onNewIntent Method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    //intent.putStringArrayListExtra("alist", alist);

     setIntent(intent);

    ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();



    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

          alist.add(query);
        //  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

          GetJson gj  =   new GetJson(this,rowItems);
         gj.delegate = this;
         gj.execute(query);



         CustomListViewAdapter adapt = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, rowItems);

            listView.setAdapter(adapt);


    }


}




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }           
    ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      GetJson gj  =   new GetJson(this,rowItems);
     gj.delegate = this;
     gj.execute("travel");



     CustomListViewAdapter adapt = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);

        listView.setAdapter(adapt);



}
```

[image: these results generated by oncreate method]

[image: onintent generating blank listview]

Comment: Is gj.execute() symchronous?

Comment: @nyarlathotep77  hmm gj is subclass of asynctask

Comment: So you should set your adapter with the data in the callback called by the asynctask. You are treating execute() as a synchronous call which is wrong. You should set the adapter with the data retrieved by the AsyncTask in onPostExecute(). Where is your implementation of that method?

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 I am getting data by rowitems not by adapter. I think i should try like u said . but why it is working for oncreate method

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 I am setting data retrieved by onPostExecute method only

Comment: I didn't mean getting data through an adapter as that's not its purpose. I said set your adapter with data in the onPostExecute() because that's the callback from your asynctask telling you that loading the data has completed.